# Add Custom Header to Spring Boot OAuth 2 Client Token Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm struggling to customize a Spring Boot 3.2.1 application with OAuth2 Client functionality. The API I am working with has a non-standard required header as part of the token request.

The end goal is to construct a WebClient to interact with the OAuth protected API.

I have the following application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          foobar:
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: xxxxxxxxxx
            client-secret: xxxxxxxxxx
        provider:
          foobar:
            token-uri: xxxxxx
```

And I have the following configuration class for constructing the WebClient so far:

```java
@Configuration
public class foobarWebClientBeans {

    @Bean
    public AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, authorizedClientService);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction foobarServerFilterFunction(AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction foobarServerFilterFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager);
        foobarServerFilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("foobar");
        return foobarServerFilterFunction;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient foobarWebClient(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction foobarServerFilterFunction) {

        return WebClient.builder()
                        .filter(foobarServerFilterFunction)
                        .baseUrl("https://foobar.com")
                        .build();
    }


}
```

The `foobar` API requires the following header for the token request: `FOOBAR UUID: xxxxx`

I see the following note in the spring documentation that seems to indicate it can be done but it doesn't really go into much detail: [Customizing the Access Token Request](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#_customizing_the_access_token_request_3) (the documentation describes parameters but there are methods for Headers as well)

Comment: I removed the tag `spring-security-oauth2`, because you are not using `spring-security-oauth2`This library is end of life since 2022 and is not compatible with Spring Boot 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging (& trial and error) I found how to modify the request.

I had to create a new `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` and add it to the Client Manager.

Before:

```java
    @Bean
    public AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, authorizedClientService);
    }
```

After:

```java
    @Bean
    public AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.addHeadersConverter(source -> {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.add("FOOBAR UUID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            return httpHeaders;
        });


        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                                                                                                                       .clientCredentials(configurer -> configurer.accessTokenResponseClient(tokenResponseClient))
                                                                                                                       .build();


        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, authorizedClientService);
        foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return foobarOauth2AuthorizedClientManager;
    }
```